# variable throwing 'undefined' error, cannot figure out

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm using Raphael.js. Everytime i load the page i get an error that reads:

```
con is undefined
x = con.x
```

I looked up `con` in the Raphael documentation, and this is what i found:

```
var con = R._getContainer.apply(0, arguments),
    container = con && con.container,
    x = con.x,
    y = con.y,
    width = con.width,
    height = con.height;
    //...
```

`con` is clearly defined here.  Here is the code I am trying to load:

```
var paper = new Raphael(ele('canvas_container'), 500, 500);

window.onload = function() {
            var circle = paper.circle(100,100,100);
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var multiplier = i * 5;
                paper.circle(250 + (2 * multiplier), 100 + multiplier, 50 - multiplier);
            }
    }
```

Has anyone else gotten this error? Is this a bug in the version of Raphael that I have or is there some other problem?

Comment: Are you sure `ele('canvas_container')` is returning what you think it is?

Comment: @Dennis-- This is what it is:`function ele(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
 }`

Comment: I guess that `paper` is a global variable. Therefore that JS would be evaluated before the DOM is ready; therefore `document.getElementById("canvas_container")` would not return what you expect.

Comment: @codeninja Are you sure that the "canvas_container" element is part of the DOM when that code runs? (Like, is the code in a `<script>` block in the `<head>`, meaning that it runs before the browser has seen the `<body>`?)

Comment: @codeninja I figured it was something like that.  If you `console.log(ele('canvas_container'))` before the `var paper` line does it give you the element?

Comment: @Pointy--the code is in the `<head>`... would placing it within the `onload()` function fix the problem? I want to avoid putting my javascript code at the bottom of the document...

Comment: @Dennis--ah, it returns `null`. Javascript does not have a `.ready()` method unless jquery is used right? How can i make sure `ele()` captures the DOM element only after the page is loaded?

Comment: @Dennis--I placed `var paper` inside the `.onload()` function and it worked. That is interesting because I always thought `onload()` was triggered at the beginning of the page load, not the end.

Comment: @codeninja jQuery *is* JavaScript.  The ready function adds an event handler that responds to a `DOMContentLoaded` event in modern browsers, with `window.load` as a fallback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try moving the paper instantiation inside your window's load function:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var paper = new Raphael(ele('canvas_container'), 500, 500);
    var circle = paper.circle(100,100,100);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var multiplier = i * 5;
        paper.circle(250 + (2 * multiplier), 100 + multiplier, 50 - multiplier);
    }
}
```

If you try to get an element by its id before the DOM is ready, `getElementById` won't return anything.  As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yDz38/), trying your code on an empty document shows the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Raphael.js expects there to be a hard coded HTML element on the page with the name of the Raphael canvas (ie: "canvas_container"). If the HTML element is created during run time (dynamically in your JavaScript code), it will throw this error.

```
R._engine.create = function () {
    var con = R._getContainer.apply(0, arguments),
        container = con && con.container,
        x = con.x,
        y = con.y,
        width = con.width,
        height = con.height;
    if (!container) {
        throw new Error("SVG container not found.");
    }
    var cnvs = $("svg"),
        css = "overflow:hidden;",
        isFloating;
    x = x || 0;
    y = y || 0;
    width = width || 512;
    height = height || 342;
    $(cnvs, {
        height: height,
        version: 1.1,
        width: width,
        xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    });
    if (container == 1) {
        cnvs.style.cssText = css + "position:absolute;left:" + x + "px;top:" + y + "px";
        R._g.doc.body.appendChild(cnvs);
        isFloating = 1;
    } else {
        cnvs.style.cssText = css + "position:relative";
        if (container.firstChild) {
            container.insertBefore(cnvs, container.firstChild);
        } else {
            container.appendChild(cnvs);
        }
    }
    container = new R._Paper;
    container.width = width;
    container.height = height;
    container.canvas = cnvs;
    container.clear();
    container._left = container._top = 0;
    isFloating && (container.renderfix = function () {});
    container.renderfix();
    return container;
};
```